# Profiling a JRUBY rails application outputs <unknown> elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profiling, jruby, jrubyonrails

Environment: Linux Mint 32 bit, JRuby-1.6.5 [ i386 ], Rails 3.1.3.

I am trying to profile my rails application deployed on JRuby 1.6.5 on WEBrick (in development mode).

My JRUBY_OPTS: "-Xlaunch.inproc=false --profile.flat"

In one of my models, I introduced an explicit sleep(5) and ensured that this method is called as part of before_save hook while saving the model. Pseudo code...

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
 <some properties here...>

 before_save :delay

 private
 def delay
  sleep(5)
 end
end
```

The above code ensures that just before an instance of Invoice gets persisted, the method, **delay** is invoked automatically.

Now, when I profile the code that creates this model instance (through an rspec unit test), I get the following output:

```
6.31        0.00        6.31          14  RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.run
6.30        0.00        6.30          14  RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.run_examples
6.30        0.00        6.30           1  RSpec::Core::Example#run
6.30        0.00        6.30           1  RSpec::Core::Example#with_around_hooks
5.58        0.00        5.58           1  <unknown>
5.43        0.00        5.43           2  Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#reload!
5.00        0.00        5.00           1  <unknown>
5.00        5.00        0.00           1  Kernel#sleep
4.87        0.00        4.87          40  ActiveSupport.execute_hook
4.39        0.00        4.39           3  ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#eval_block
4.38        0.00        4.38           2  Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#load_paths
```

In the above output, why do I see those two  elements instead of Invoice.delay or something similar.

In fact, when I start my rails server (WEBrick) with the same JRUBY_OPTS (mentioned above), all my application code frames show up as **unknown** elements in the profiler output !

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: How are you getting the output from WEBrick?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you max of the profile methods limit
`Set -Xprofile.max.methods JRUBY_OPTS` to a big number (default is 100000 and is never enough). E.g.

```
export JRUBY_OPTS="--profile.flat -Xprofile.max.methods=10000000"
```